# Alienware GPU in a rpi will it work?

Tags: raspi-config, diy

I obtained an Alienware GPU and was wondering if there was anyway to hook it up to an rpi?
[GPU I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0O6y.jpg)

Comment: If that card is a regular PCI-e graphics card I don't think you'll get anywhere with it. There is nothing to interface the card with on the Pi and no exposed PCI-e bus. Perhaps some USB->GPU contraption but USB2 is nowhere near fast enough for display purposes (and on the Pi this is already contended) and you might struggle with drivers long before that.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, it's not possible. There's no PCI bus. There's no external interfaces to the ARM GPU other than HDMI, CSI (camera) and DSI (RPF official touch screen).